# Percentage calculation of specific number of row over total

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, percentage

I'm looking for SELECT statement to calculate percentage of specific number of row over the total number of rows.
For example; lets say i have a FRUIT table like this;

[image: table]

I want to calculate a percentage of rows that its name is not peach, over the total number of rows. I try this statement :

```
SELECT CAST((select count(name) from fruit WHERE name !='peach') 
as FLOAT) /
            (select count(name)from fruit)*100.0 as percentage ;
```

but it doesn't give me correct number. I also need a statement that i can calculate percentage of each fruit by grouping them with Group by  function

I'm very new at SQL and i keep trying but cant find the right syntax. Please help me.

Comment: How does your query not work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is using conditional aggregation with average:

```
select avg(case when fruit <> 'peach' then 100.0 else 0.0 end)
from fruits;
```

In Postgres, you can use the shorthand:

```
select 100*avg((fruit <> 'peach')::int)
from fruits;
```